# How to process words and numbers in a file in python

Tags: python, file

- Hello I'm a few weeks into python and now learning files. I've made the program be able to sum the numbers in the file if there were only numbers but now there are numbers aswell as words. How do I make it ignore the words and make it sum to 186?

```
def sum_numbers_in_file(filename):
    """reads all the numbers in a file and returns the sum of the numbers"""
    filename = open(filename)
    lines = filename.readlines() 
    result = 0
    for num in lines:
        result = result + int(num)
        num.rstrip()
    filename.close()
    return result

answer = sum_numbers_in_file('sum_nums_test_01.txt')
print(answer)
```

This is in the file:

```
1
Pango
2
Whero
3
4
10
Kikorangi
20
40
100
-3
4
5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily add a try-except statement inside the function to make it work only on numbers:

```
def sum_numbers_in_file(filename):
    """reads all the numbers in a file and returns the sum of the numbers"""
    filename = open(filename)
    lines = filename.readlines() 
    result = 0
    for num in lines:
        try:
            result = result + int(num)
            num.rstrip()
        except ValueError:
            pass
    filename.close()
    return result

answer = sum_numbers_in_file('sum_nums_test_01.txt')
print(answer)
```

Or you can use the isalpha method:

```
def sum_numbers_in_file(filename):
    """reads all the numbers in a file and returns the sum of the numbers"""
    filename = open(filename)
    lines = filename.readlines() 
    result = 0
    for num in lines:
        num = num.rstrip()
        if not num.isalpha():
            result = result + int(num)
    filename.close()
    return result

answer = sum_numbers_in_file('sum_nums_test_01.txt')
print(answer)
```

The isalpha() returns true only if the string doesn't contain symbols or numbers, so you can use it to check if the string is a number. Also works on decimal numbers.
Note that it also detects symbols as numbers, so if there's a symbol in the line it will count that as a number, potentially generating errors!

Comment: Thanks for helping, is there a way to do it without a try except (the code checker I'm using doesn't allow its usage which is quite frustrating).

Comment: I also recommend you to use a context manager, to avoid opening and closing the file each time

Comment: Thanks for the edit however it comes up with this error? builtins.ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Pango\n'

Comment: Ohh, I see, the string also contains "\n", which make the condition True. You also have to remove the last two characters of each string in order to make this work

Comment: Could it be because of the newline? I even copied straight from your code and gave same error.

Comment: You can exclude the last two characters of each line by writing "if not num[:-2].isalpha()", assuming **every single line ends with a "\n**.

Comment: Thanks that fixes it, however I'm unsure why num.rstrip didn't remove the newline?

Comment: Because it gets executed after the conditional check. If you do it before the if statement, it should work! I edited my post, you can check my new solution.

Comment: i put it in the for loop but before the if statement but it still comes up with the previous error?

Comment: My bad! The rstrip() function doesn't modify the string in-place. You have to assign it to the new value, so you have to write num = num.rstrip() before the if statement, or you can write not num.rstrip().isalpha() as the condition

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **try-except block**, an advanced yet effective way of preventing errors. Add this in your for loop:

```py
try:
    result += int(num)
except: pass
```

Normally it's a good practice to add something in the except clause but we don't want anything so we just `pass`. The `try`means we try but if we fail we go to the except part.

Comment: Thanks for helping, is there a way to do it without a try except (the code checker I'm using doesn't allow its usage which is quite frustrating).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a `try/except` block:

```
with open("words.txt") as f:
    nums = []
    for l in f:
        try:
            nums.append(float(l))
        except ValueError:
            pass

    result = sum(nums)
```

A simple one-liner that you could implement to get all numerical values if you want an alternative would be:

```
with open("words.txt") as f:
    nums = [float(l.strip()) for l in f if not l.strip().isalpha()]

    result = sum(nums)
```

Here, I convert each line into a float and append that value to the nums list. If the line is not a numerical value, it will simply just be passed over, hence `pass`.

You cannot use `.isnumeric()` as it will only work for strings that contain only integers. This means no decimals or negative numbers.

Comment: In my current code would not if num.isnumeric() == True: not work if put into the for loop?

Comment: Unfortunately you cannnot use `.isnumeric()` because it does not pick up on negative numbers or decimals.

Answer (score 0):

Here are couple of way's you can try using [`isdigit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit),

```
value = 0

with open("sum_nums_test_01.txt") as f:
    for l in f.readlines():
        if l.strip().isdigit():
            value += int(l)
```

---

```
with open("sum_nums_test_01.txt") as f:
    value = sum(int(f) for f in f.readlines() if f.strip().isdigit())
```